# Export from Sql To Excel, changing data in excel and return updated data to Sql

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

I saw a lot of answers about export/import sql to excel. I have a difficult question.
I want toExport from Sql To Excel, then i want to change the data in excel with functions - for example:

every salary will get 10% Bonus - then, I want to take this updated data and return it right to the place i took it from.

I also want to do it with a query:
Example:

```
ID    NAME   SALARY  CAR
123   BOB    130     Ford
332   Katie  140     Toyota
431   Bil    160     Ford
```

I want to Export To Excel Just The people who have `Ford` and their `Salary`
Then, In Excel I want to add 10% for Their Salary
Then I want to send it back to Sql and replace the old Salary with the new one.

I'm using **SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO, SQL SERVER 2008 R2**

Comment: why export to Excel?  just do this in SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
UPDATE table1
SET Salary = Salary * 1.1
```

and for when someone has a Ford then do

```
UPDATE table1
SET Salary = Salary * 1.1
WHERE Car = 'Ford'
```

you will also have to make sure that the Data Type for Salary is going to accept Decimals or float values otherwise you might get an error.

these are untested queries